# Java generics: Does "T2 extends T1" imply "T1 super T2"?

Tags: java, generics, collections, option-type

If I have a generic `<T2 extends T1>`, does the compiler infer `T1 super T2`?

I have a more complex collection, which I reduced to the MWE below. The collection shall be mergeable with any such collection with elements of any subtype.

Now I'm wondering, why the call to `forEach` in `merge` is not accepted. It fails with

> java.util.function.Consumer<java.util.Optional> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Consumer<java.util.Optional<? super T2>>

I've depicted the type relationships in the diagram below. In `merge`, `T2` extends `T1`. The call to `forEach` is applied on the `other` object, hence the `T1` of `this` becomes the `?` of `other.forEach` and the `T2` of `this.merge` is the `T1` of `other`. Hence, `this`' `T1` should be accepted as super of `other`'s `T1`.

I also tried `public void merge(Group<? extends T> other)` with the same result. And `public void merge(Group<T> other)` does not accept such collections with elements of any subtype of `T1`.

MWE:

```
class Group<T1> {
    public <T2 extends T1> void merge(Group<T2> other) {
        Consumer<Optional<T1>> task = t -> t.ifPresentOrElse(this::foo, this::bar);
        other.forEach(task);
    }

    public Collection<Optional<T1>> values() {
        return List.of();
    }

    public void forEach(Consumer<Optional<? super T1>> consumer) {
        values().forEach(consumer);
    }

    private void foo(T1 t) {}

    private void bar() {}
}
```

Relationships:

```
   this.T1      -becomes->  other.forEach.?
      ^                            |
      |                          super
   extends                         |
      |                            v
this.merge.T2     -is->        other.T1
```

Comment: To make the main problem obvious: `List<List<? super String>>` is not compatible with `List<List<String>>`. You may want to try `Consumer<? super Optional<T1>>`, with `task` being declared as `Consumer<Optional<T2>> task`. There's no reason to make `task` a `Consumer<Optional<T1>>`

Comment: The List example makes sense, thanks. `Consumer<Optional<T2>> task` doesn't work as it wouldn't accept `this::forEach` anymore

Comment: And `Consumer<? super Optional<T1>>` doesn't help as `Optional` is a final class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem using

```java
class Group<T1> {
    public <T2 extends T1> void merge(Group<T2> other) {
        Consumer<Optional<? extends T1>> task=t->t.ifPresentOrElse(this::foo, this::bar);
        other.forEach(task);
    }

    public Collection<Optional<T1>> values() {
        return List.of();
    }

    public void forEach(Consumer<? super Optional<T1>> consumer) {
        values().forEach(consumer);
    }

    private void foo(T1 t) {}

    private void bar() {}
}
```

This is an application of the [PECS rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488).

Your `task` will treat the `Optional` as a *producer*, hence, has to declare `Optional<? extends T1>` to allow the optional to produce subtypes of `T1`. We know that optional will always act as a producer, but Java’s generic type system does not have the concept of classes always acting like a producer or consumer and needs an explicit `? extends T1` here.

The `forEach` receives a consumer, even literally in the interface name, so `? super …` is the right way to declare that this consumer may be a consumer of supertypes of `Optional<T1>`. This does not only include `Object`, the superclass of `Optional`, but also `Optional<? extends T1>` when `T1 := T2`, as in the invocation within `merge`, as `Optional<? extends T1>` is a supertype of `Optional<T2>`.

---

Of course, you could also solve the issue by simply using

```java
Consumer<Optional<T2>> task = t -> t.ifPresentOrElse(this::foo, this::bar);
```

as this only requires `foo` to accept a `T2` argument, which it always does, as `T2` is a subtype of `T1`. But changing the signature of `forEach` to raise the flexibility is always a good move. Since it’s a `public` method, there might be other callers benefitting from it.

Comment: This works. Interestingly, your second version and `forEach` kept flexible with super works as well, i.e., `Consumer<Optional<T2>> task` is also accepted by `forEach(Consumer<Optional<? super T1>>)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Consumer<Optional<? super T1>> consumer` then you can pass it (to the `accept(T)` method) an `Optional<Object>` because `Object` is a supertype of `T1`.

On the other hand, you cannot pass an `Optional<Object>` to `Consumer<Optional<T1>> task` because `T1` might not be `Object`.

So you cannot assign the `Consumer<Optional<T1>> task` to the `Consumer<Optional<? super T1>> consumer` to prevent your consumer from being passed objects of types it does not expect.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that the wildcard is not bound at the top